# Barbarians spawning even though barbarians are turned off

Tags: civilization-5

I'm playing as America, and this is in around the classical/medieval era, and Aztec declared war against me for no reason at all. I had the worst army in the game but took over 4/5 of his cities before he surrendered.

Then there were notifications telling me that there are enemies spotted around one of my cities, and it turned out to be 2 barbarian longswords men, and then there were 2 more spearmen that spawned at the same place, then there were 2 horsemen spawned in the city to the north of Aztec's capital.

Is this a glitch? I have 23 unhappiness, and it fluctuates between that and 21 very often, and my income fluctuates between -2 to 8.

Never had this happen before. And it seems that Barbarians spawn in pairs, and they don't spawn more until the pair is killed

Comment: You should be aiming to 0 or positive happiness at all times. Build the necessary buildings and take the right bonuses in the (purple) trait tree that match your play style.

Comment: In extreme unhappiness scenarios, buildings and bonuses might not be fast enough.  Determine which cities you don't need and raze them if you have time or gift them to another civ if you need happy now.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Barbarians might spawn in your territory when your population is very unhappy. You can tell if your population is very unhappy by an angry looking happiness icon. THere are several other consequences from your population being unhappy:

> When your happiness is negative and your happiness icon is looking angry, your population is "very unhappy." If your population is very unhappy, your cities stop growing altogether, you cannot build any Settlers, your military units get a nasty combat penalty, and rebel(barbarian) units may spawn inside of your territory.

Source: [Civilization V wiki happiness section](http://wiki.2kgames.com/civ5/index.php/Happiness#Levels_of_Unhappiness)

Answer (score 1):

You have so much unhappiness that you reached the Unrest(Very Unhappy) level. (and you've actually gone past the Unrest level) On this unhappiness level,barbarians will spawn on your territory,cities won't grow,and you can't build cities. Try to build buildings that provide happiness,acquire luxury resources,discover natural wonders,get a mercantile city-state to be your friend or ally,or,if you are desperate,you can starve your city until it reaches a smaller size (this will give you also many disadvantages) to reduce unhappiness until your citizens are merely unhappy (look for the unhappiness icon;if it looks sad,your people are unhappy,if a bit angry,your people is very unhappy. If even more angry they are very angry. Just increase your happiness until your people is happy or unhappy. Also,unhappiness provides,for each point of unhappiness,a penalty of 2% on gold,production,and combat.